# What is javascript POST request sending exactly while used as a GET request?

Tags: javascript, python, api

I have an API accepts POST request while no parameter or data is required. The following post request in Javascript works fine.

```
function ban () {
    let user_id = $('#user_id').val();
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'myApiUrl');
    form.style.display = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(form)
    form.submit();
}
```

But with Python `requests.post("myApiUrl")`, it gives 401 Response. What did I miss?

Comment: if you do not know already, 401 is unauthorized meaning your post request in python does not have the right authorization to access the API. Without seeing the python code, it's hard to tell what's happening. The Auth header, Bearer token are probably not set, no values, etc.

Comment: @jmesolomon - as there are no such headers being sent in the JS code, it's probably a lack of *cookie*

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! I think you hit the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I figured it out.

I think this API does require authorization but it could be a Cookie-based auth. The JS code worked because I have logged in before in the same browser and JS code read the authorization content from the cookies.